# Can GWT be configured to create cache files in other location than the user's home folder?

Tags: java, gwt, caching

I have a large project which I am compiling with GWT. During this process GWT generates some cache files in `C:\Documents and Settings\[UserDir]\Local Settings\Temp\`. For example:

```
gwt60627byte-cache (86,321 KB)
gwt60628byte-cache (4,445 KB)
gwt60629byte-cache (53,773 KB)
gwt60696byte-cache (8,111 KB)
gwt60697byte-cache (572,777 KB)
```

I know GWT’s performance isn’t that great, and there are not a lot of things to do speed it up, but my project is on drive D: which is faster than C:, so I want to move these cache files on the same drive.

But that is not the primary reason. I am also concerned about the size of these files reported to the free space I have left on C: (which ain't much). I am not doing a full project compile yet, but when I do I don't think the HDD will handle it.

How can I have these cache files generated in another location?

Thank you.

Comment: Just change your `TEMP` environment variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GWT compiler has a -workDir option that defaults to the system temp directory. You can change that to have the cache files written somewhere else.

Comment: This is the "by the book" solution. Also, a workaround that performed well for my setup was to change the TEMP environment variable as Mirko Nasato suggested in his comment.

Comment: On Windows 7 I had to change the TMP environment variable to achieve this, not the TEMP variable.

Answer (score 11):

The -workDir option in the GWT compiler only controls the location where the "gwt-unitCache-*" files are  generated.

To change the location where  other GWT temporary files are generated (mainly, the "gwt*byte-cache", "uiBinder*" and "ImageResourceGenerator*.png" files), the only option is to change the value of the "java.io.tmpdir" Java system property through the command line (e.g. "-Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/custom/temp/directory".

If using Maven, you can declare  this property in the <extraJvmArgs> element of the <configuration> section for the gwt-maven-plugin, within the <plugins> or <pluginManagement> section, likewise:

.../...

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${gwt.maven.plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <extraJvmArgs>-Djava.io.tmpdir=${project.build.directory}</extraJvmArgs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>

.../...
```

In this example the temporary GWT files will be generated in ${project.build.directory} , that is the "target" directory of the GWT project being compiled.

The <extraJvmArgs> is also the place where you would define any JVM memory settings to be used by the GWT compiler, such as "-Xmx1024m" for instance.

Comment: with Eclipse Kepler and GWT 2.5.1 going to `eclipse preferences > java > installed JREs > Edit > Default VM args` and setting it to `-Djava.io.tmpdir=E:/tmp` worked for me too